# How to resolve "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, development, document-library, csom

I am creating a C# Solution that will migrate the documents from SharePoint 2010 On-Premises to SharePoint Online.

I am done with the program. But when I run the program it runs successfully for few times. After some time it starts throwing error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: The sign-in name or
>   password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.

I am unable to track the actual error.

Here I am sharing my code:

```
public void CreateFolderStructures(MigrationFolders migrationFolders)
{
    using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("Site URL")
    {
        string SPOnlineUsername = "Username";
        string SPOnlinePassword = "PASSWORD";
        foreach (char c in SPOnlinePassword)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(SPOnlineUsername, securePassword);
        var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocumentLibraryName);
        ListItemCreationInformation newItemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        newItemInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
        newItemInfo.LeafName = migrationFolders.FolderName;
        newItemInfo.FolderUrl = "SITEURL" + migrationFolders.FolderPath;
        ListItem newListItem = list.AddItem(newItemInfo);
        newListItem.Update();
        list.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        newListItem["Modified"] = migrationFolders.ModifiedDDate;
        newListItem["Created"] = migrationFolders.CreatedDate;
        newListItem.Update();
        list.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   }
}
```

The above code is called in `foreach` loop.

I have gone through following URL but that is not the case with me.

- [How to resolve error “Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system” when using CSOM for O365/SharePoint online](http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-resolve-error.html)
- [SharePoint: The sign-in name or password does not match one in the
  Microsoft account system.](http://kb.cloudiway.com/sharepoint-the-sign-in-name-or-password-does-not-match-one-in-the-microsoft-account-system/)
- [Office 365 : Connecting to SharePoint online site using CSOM when
  Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) is enabled for the user](https://knowledge-junction.com/2017/12/24/office-365-connecting-to-sharepoint-online-site-using-csom-when-multi-factor-authentication-mfa-is-enabled-for-the-user/)

Any suggestion how to resolve this error?

**Note:** I tried by declaring clientcontext globally in the program but still no luck.

Comment: are you using the correct DLLs ? For SPO, you need to use the SharePoint Online CSOM dlls with version 16. Do try with the latest from nuget

Comment: Let me check that too.

Comment: The nuget package name is `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` and the latest version is `16.1.7521.1200`. You should be using that to connect to your SharePoint Online site

Comment: Same issue. One folder created successfully. After that error starts "`The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.`

Comment: are you using external user account or a Microsoft account ? These accounts wont work. You need to use the work account (not personal account) to connect to SPO. Also, check if you are using `myuser@tenantname.sharepoint.com` instead of `myuser@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: I am using `username@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com` account. It seems the token in `ClientContext` is getting expired or something similar.

Comment: Hi Akakash did you every find a solution for this? I'm getting the same issue, but only after publishing my site to Azure.. it works fine locally

Comment: Let me post it as an answer.

Comment: Hi Aakash, were you able to resolve the issue? I am also having a similar problem.